# If HashMap containskey(Any part of a String)

Tags: java, string, if-statement, hashmap

The question sounds a bit weird but I can explain it:
I have a HashMap filled with Strings as keys and values. And I have a String. Now I want to do something like that:

```
if(myhashmap.containskey(ANY PART OF MY STRING)
```

Like:

```
String str = "Java is cool!";
[HashMap that contains following : "Java";
```

I want that I can check if a String contains something.
Maybe I could do that with a for loop but there is nothing like hashmap.entry.
What would you do?

Comment: Find a different data structure; use a for loop on the "parts" of your `String`; your `HashMap` is organized by the *`hashCode()`* of the key(s) in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "any part of"?  Do you mean any word in the string?  Or any substring?  Or something else?  For example, if the key were `"va is co"`, would you expect your code to be able to find it?

Comment: you can iterate over the _keySet_, but is sound like you want a different data structure

Answer (score 6):

You can loop over the keys of the map and check if they are in the string:

```
String str = "Java is cool!";
Map<String, ...> map = ...;

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    if (str.contains(key)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you also need the associated value for the `key`, [you can use `entrySet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map).

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with stream and filtering, which is pretty functional :)

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Hello World", 1);
map.put("Challo World", 2);
map.put("Hallo World", 3);
map.put("Hello Universe", 4);
map.put("Hello Cosmos", 5);

List<Integer> values =
    map.keySet().stream()
       .filter(key -> key.contains("World"))
       .map(map::get)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You should get a `List<Integer>` with values 1,2,3.